# Navigation component and Splash Screen API

Tags: android-navigation, android-splashscreen

I just migrated my splash screen activity to the new splash screen API ((https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen)).

I am also using the Navigation component to move from the Main activity to a secondary activity.

So far I am able to open the main activity. This is the onCreate() method within the main activity.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    installSplashScreen()
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    ...
```

within the fragment of the main activity I call

```
findNavController().navigate(directions)
```

to navigate to the second activity and the app crashes with:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

If I call `installSplashScreen()` in the second activity, it works, but on some devices I get:

```
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{xxx/SecondActivity}: androidx.fragment.app.o$d: Unable to instantiate fragment ab.q: could not find Fragment constructor
```

Thanks.

Comment: did you solve this problem? I got the same problem with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `installSplashScreen()` in tje second activity is correct.
The problem with other was due to the fact that I had a nested fragment with arguments constructor.
I refactored the fragment to no args constructor by using bundle to set the argument and it all works now.